# Safely distribute ec2 key pairs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

What is a good way to safely distribute EC2 Keypairs amongst team members? I have considered using Signed URLs, but that would leave it open if someone outside somehow got the url.

Is there a way to require a user to login with their IAM credentials to access a URL in s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way to distribute key pairs of any kind to other users is through an existing server that they already have access to. For example, if my team already has accounts on an existing server, I will drop a copy of the keys into files in their home directories. Or I will give group access to a directory that they all have access to. If you are on secured LAN that users are local to or that can VPN into you can also setup a shared folder.

If you do not have such resources, you can use encrypted email, but that can take a bit of setup.

Another option is secure chats (IM or IRC). Some IM clients (eg Adium (for Mac)) use OTR (Off The Record) to encrypt private conversations.

Yes, S3 has multiple options for allowing access to individual files. You can give access to "Authenticated Users", which would apply to IAM users. You can also assign IAM roles and group policies. Using IAM you can create very granular permissions for users to just about any AWS service.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like your preferred method and will probably implement it. Currently I'm giving my IAM users access to only create keypairs. They login to the console and create the keypair from there.